# Group by 'column name' doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch category name from which has been saved multiple times before. So to fetch the name i need to group the name so it doesn't display multiple times, however i tried doing it in the way mentioned before and have failed so far. 
I'm sure i am doing something horribly wrong here and i am just not able to find why am i not able to group it. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
$valsubcat=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT categoryid 
                               FROM subcategorymaster 
                               WHERE subcatid=$valitem1[0]");

while($valsubcat1=mysqli_fetch_array($valsubcat))
{
    $valcat=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT CategoryName 
                                FROM categorymaster 
                                WHERE categoryid=$valsubcat1[0] 
                                GROUP BY CategoryName");
    while($valcat1=mysqli_fetch_array($valcat)) 
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$valcat1[0]."</td></tr>";   
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the group by and doing SELECT DISTINCT instead?

Comment: Can you show an example of the raw data, and the result you're getting now, and what you want ?  Because the Group By will return singular results for each select. However you have that running in a loop. If the same Category shows up in several queries, you will have that duplication.  Maybe better to Select all CategoryName's where the ID's are in the list, and then use Group By or Distinct on the combined result sets of all the queries..

Comment: Good grief. See JOIN !!!

Comment: @Amir [imgur](http://imgur.com/a/k3PqR) The above photo is how i am getting it and the photo below is how i want it.
I have grouped the dates to show the amount i spent on that day. 
And just like that what im trying to achieve here is group the categories together and then display the amount spent on each category.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm really kind of new to all this. :(

Comment: Oh one of those questions: where the requirements keep on changing with each answer given!

Comment: RiggsFolly's answer can be adapted to the changing requirements of your question. But if you're still struggling, get rid of all this PHP and instead provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements TOGETHER WITH a desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce that to one query using a JOIN

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT scm.categoryid, cm.CategoryName
        FROM subcategorymaster as scm
            LEFT JOIN categorymaster cm ON cm.categoryid = scm.categoryid
        WHERE scm.subcatid = {$valitem1[0]}");
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that so i just looped the hell outta of those things

Comment: Well test this query in phpMyAdmin or something similiar to make sure it does what I think you were trying to do. If it works, amend your PHP to use the results

Comment: [imgur](http://imgur.com/a/k3PqR) the above photo is how i am getting it and the photo below is how i want it. I have grouped the dates to show the amount i spent on that day. And just like that what im trying to achieve here is group the categories together and then display the amount spent on each category. @riggsfolly